# How to use less css with django?

Tags: python, django, less

I'm using twitter bootstrap and django. I've got my dependencies handled with a pip requirements file.

I've got 2 questions:

1. How can I use less while I'm developing so it'll get compiled when I edit one of my less files?
2. How can I create some kind of build script that will compress and combine my JS and generate CSS from Less as part of a deployment?

I've written a custom build script that creates a virtualenv, runs 'pip install -r requirements.txt', django syncdb, django migrate and then off we go.

What's the easiest way of integrating less into this?

Thanks

Answer (score 45, accepted):

1. **Install [django-static-precompiler](https://github.com/andreyfedoseev/django-static-precompiler)**:
2. Run `pip install django-static-precompiler`
3. Add `static_precompiler` to INSTALLED_APPS
4. **Install [lessc](http://lesscss.org/#-client-side-usage) executable**, either via your package manager or run `npm install less` (**npm is node package manager**, which should be distro-installable, use at last resort)
5. **Use less in templates**:
6. **Load the template tag**: `{% load less %}`
7. **Use less template tag**: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL}}{% less "path/to/styles.less" %}" />`

**Note that** by default compiled files are saved into `COMPILED` folder under your `STATIC_ROOT` (or `MEDIA_ROOT` if you have no `STATIC_ROOT` in your settings). You can change this folder name with `STATIC_PRECOMPILER_OUTPUT_DIR` setting. See the [documentation](http://django-static-precompiler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) for further details.

I didn't try it personally but i know that [django-compressor](https://django-compressor.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) also supports less.

Comment: I prefer django-compressor as it does more helpful things for me, and can compile both scss and coffeescript

Comment: The problem with all does apps is that they don't monitor @include'd files for changes ...

Comment: @jpic, here's the solution for less css: http://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2012/03/05/using-less-django/ The JS interpreter can run client-side, though slowly. So if DEBUG=True, you use the JS interpreter, which eliminates monitoring for changes.

Comment: Absolutely, that looks like [how I use lesscss and twitter bootstrap nowadays](http://blog.yourlabs.org/post/40243673811/bootstrap-lesscss-and-django) - which includes having less in debug mode too !

Comment: I also had to add 'less.finders.LessFinder' to STATICFILES_FINDERS in settings.

Comment: I'm the author of `django-less` and I recommend to use `django-static-precompiler` (which I'm developing as well). It's universal (Less, SCSS, Coffeescript and more coming), it monitors the included files, and has a nice `static_precompiler_watch` management command. It's compatible with `django-less` so you don't need to update your code.

Answer (score 15):

The selected answer is now out of date: `django-less` is no longer being maintained (as specified on [its pypi page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-less)), and the developer suggests using [django-static-precompiler](https://github.com/andreyfedoseev/django-static-precompiler) instead.